# Kendo culture for number format in a kendo text box

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a text box and its value is "1234567890.123456789123" .
I want this value to be cultured based on kendo number format .ie if the kendo.culture().numberFormat["."]= . then the value should be

1,234,567,890.123456789

Basically kendo supports number format for only numerictextbox .

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Try by adding the number formatting in the text box change event

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand exactly, but you can set format of numerictextbox.

```
kendo.ui.NumericTextBox.fn.options.format = "0.00"
```